# Limited formatting Word Processor

Tags: microsoft-word

I need a word processor with limited formatting options (I'll limit them..) for use in a group.
Currently we use MSWord and the documents are messy, with all kinds of fonts, colors etc etc..

I'd like to impose a single character, 3 possible sizes and something like that..

Solutions I thought of are:

- Style locking in MSWord (problem: doesn't work on the mac version)
- Write my own editor in Adobe Air based on the Rich Text Editor (last solution since it's time consuming)
- Get people to write txt files like Textile and associate a css, then generate PDFs (2 problems: 1 it's difficult for end users since they don't see the formatting in real time, 2 it's difficult to create pdf in real time since I use dropbox as a sharing mechanism and I don't have a PC always on..)

Any brilliant idea?

Comment: ::dons fanboy hat:: Dude, use LaTeX, man! It's killer. ::doffs fanboy hat:: But frankly, if your group members won't discipline themselves, they won't discipline themselves...

Comment: Get rid of the students

Answer (score 0):

The best way probably to solve this without too much trouble is to teach your group a simple markup language like Markdown. It won't really hinder your productivity once you get a bit used to it and it'll be way easier to read your documents as well as being way more exportable.